# XPages error message: Invalid persisted content session id:

Tags: xpages

We have a document management application buit using XPages, running on a Domino 9.0.1 server, and we get this error quite often lately:

```
Invalid persisted content session id: .
```

Anyone knows where that could be coming from? Possible cause?  Server or app settings that can cause this?

I did a Google search and didn't find anything...  not one result...

Here is the stack trace:

```
Page Name: /page.xsp
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid persisted content session id: .
    at com.ibm.xsp.persistence.AbstractPersistedContent.(AbstractPersistedContent.java:42)
    at com.ibm.xsp.persistence.FilePersistedContent.(FilePersistedContent.java:46)
    at com.ibm.xsp.persistence.FilePersistenceService.createPersistedContent(FilePersistenceService.java:73)
    at com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoRichTextItem.getPersistedContent(DominoRichTextItem.java:3086)
    at com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoRichTextItem.extractCID(DominoRichTextItem.java:1393)
    at com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoRichTextItem.extractMimeText(DominoRichTextItem.java:1341)
    at com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoRichTextItem.getRichTextMime(DominoRichTextItem.java:1280)
    at com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoRichTextItem.getHTML(DominoRichTextItem.java:392)
    at com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoRichTextItem.toString(DominoRichTextItem.java:378)
    at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.convertValue(FacesUtil.java:1146)
    at com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_basic.ReadOnlyRteRenderer.encodeText(ReadOnlyRteRenderer.java:86)
    at com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_basic.ReadOnlyRteRenderer.encodeValue(ReadOnlyRteRenderer.java:50)
    at com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_basic.ReadOnlyValueRenderer.encodeBegin(ReadOnlyValueRenderer.java:69)
    at com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeBegin(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:146)
    at com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeBegin(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:146)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:956)
    at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:842)
    at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)
    at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)
    at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)
    at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)
    at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)
    at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.renderkit.html_extended.layout.AbstractApplicationLayoutRenderer.renderChildren(AbstractApplicationLayoutRenderer.java:1401)
    at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.renderkit.html_extended.layout.AbstractApplicationLayoutRenderer.writeContentColumn(AbstractApplicationLayoutRenderer.java:1203)
    at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.renderkit.html_extended.layout.AbstractApplicationLayoutRenderer.writeMainContent(AbstractApplicationLayoutRenderer.java:1105)
    at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.renderkit.html_extended.layout.AbstractApplicationLayoutRenderer.writeMainFrame(AbstractApplicationLayoutRenderer.java:237)
    at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.renderkit.html_extended.layout.AbstractApplicationLayoutRenderer.encodeBegin(AbstractApplicationLayoutRenderer.java:1367)
    at com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeBegin(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:146)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:956)
    at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.layout.UIVarPublisherBase.encodeBegin(UIVarPublisherBase.java:112)
    at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:842)
    at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)
    at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)
    at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)
    at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)
    at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)
    at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:853)
    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx._renderView(UIViewRootEx.java:1317)
    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.renderView(UIViewRootEx.java:1255)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.doRender(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:651)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:321)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:336)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:103)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:210)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:120)
    at com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.render(FacesControllerImpl.java:270)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:261)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:157)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:576)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1335)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:853)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:796)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:565)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1319)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:662)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:482)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:357)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:313)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
```

Comment: Any stacktraces? Where is this coming from, the Domino console? Xpages front end message or error page? You could check the logs in the ibm_technical_support folder for stacktraces.

Comment: This error comes from the file persistance service (which handles f.e. the attachments for CKEditor). The error is thrown because there is no session id available. Maybe a crawler trying to access some attachments directly?

Comment: Added stack trace to original post...

Comment: So does that mean that trying to access an image built with a src such as http://myserver/mydb.nsf/xsp/.ibmmodres/persistence/DominoDoc-CF5A-Body/_1_143748574767263-486C.gif  generates this error because the file isn't there anymore???

Comment: @BenDubuc: Yes, this can cause the error.